# Android cannot draw transparent rectangle on canvas

Tags: android, graphics

TRY draw with transparent background and draw lines on it. 
However it draws a black rectangle instead of transparet.
If I change the color to red, it works alright.
So I guess it's the problem of transparent.

```
       drawPoints[currentpoint*4+0] = 0; 
       drawPoints[currentpoint*4+1] = 10;
       drawPoints[currentpoint*4+2] = 20; 
       drawPoints[currentpoint*4+3] = 40;

        Canvas mCanvas = sfh.lockCanvas(new Rect(10,20,50,100));
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);           
        mCanvas.drawLines(drawPoints,mPaint);
        sfh.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);
```

Why it draws black?

Answer (score 7):

If you want transparency, you could try:

```
mPaint.setAlpha(100);
```

or some value between 0 and 255.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the Paint object's color to Color.TRANSPARENT, rather than the canvas' color. So try

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this on the internet, I think that can works

```
Paint pincel1=new Paint();
paint.setARGB(255,255,0,0);

canvas.drawRect(10,10,ancho-10,40,pincel1);

pincel1.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawRect(10,60,ancho-10,90,pincel1);

pincel1.setStrokeWidth(3);
canvas.drawRect(10,110,ancho-10,140,pincel1);
```

[image http://www.javaya.com.ar/androidya/imagentema/foto137.jpg](http://www.javaya.com.ar/androidya/imagentema/foto137.jpg)

thx **javaya.com/ar** for the code

[code](http://www.javaya.com.ar/androidya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=169&inicio=20)